# Angularjs test if scope variable is undefined or null

Tags: angularjs

my code my controller:

```
App.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
   console.log("CTRL STARTED");

   if (angular.isDefined($scope.test)) <--------------- ERROR
      {
         alert('UNDEFINITA');
         LoadDefault();
      };
```

My HTML

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-options="people.id as people.name for people in      peoples" ng-model="test" ng-change="LoadAnotherSelect()">
    <option value="">Seleziona azienda...</option>
 </select>
```

How to know if test variable is undefined???? 
Thank's in advanced

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your code seems fine,
what error are you getting?

as you can see, this code works, using `angular.isDefined($scope.name)`:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  if (angular.isDefined($scope.name)) {
    alert($scope.name);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Nitsan, if get error "undefined is not a function...Thanks.

Comment: @Aesis are you sure the error comes from isDefined? what version of angular?

Comment: Yes, Angular 1.2.26 Error: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: @Aesis as you see in the answer, the code runs fine. your error comes from elsewhere. please post a plnkr/fiddle and reproduce the error

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y3zvxm4g/ this is my code! The error is when call "caricaAziende()" from if. Why? Thank's

Comment: But the problem is only in function order? Wheere i find the documentation of this order or style? Thank's now works!